# Extract ASCII cells geographical position

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a task where I need to locate the geographical coordinates from a series of cells (indexed as row/column numbers) from an ASCII raster.

How can I do that in ArcGIS?

I know the header of the raster, with the starting x, y and the cell size. Is there a formula to find obtain the coordinates from that?

Comment: You have everything you need; you just need to remember that raster origins are usually from the upper-left corner, so Y values are subtracted.  Also be careful for whether the UL corner is presented as the "center-center" of the UL cell or the upper-left corner of the UL cell.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in ArcGIS you can simply bring it in and convert it (use the ASCII to Raster) tool in "Conversion Tools" (under "To Raster"). Then you have your raster so you can convert it to Points (use "Raster to Point" under "From Raster" also in "Conversion Tools". Next you can just add 2 fields (make them type double) and calculate geometry for each. That will give you points with x and y coordinates for every point. They should also retain their value from the grid.

To summarize

1. Ascii to Raster
2. Raster to Point
3. Add fields for X and Y, (or Long, Lat if the raster is in a geographic coordinate system).
4. Calculate Geometry for each using the X coordinate and Y coordinate.

**Note:** you can override the coordinate system and calculate lat long if you use the data frame.

The header only gives you the one center. You could potentially devise a method of deriving the coordinate values, but this is a pretty easy way to do this and you could script this with Arcpy or do it right in ArcMap.

Comment: Conversion is a very big price to pay for basic math operations mentioned in @Vince comment